# cmake fails to find OpenSSL libs (cpp-netlib)

Tags: openssl, cmake, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to build the cpp-netlib on windows (8.1) with VS2013 (express).
When I run cmake:
`C:\...\build\cmake ..\source -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

it writes:

> Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in
>   the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES)
>   (found version "0.9.8h")

I installed OpenSSL using the GnuWin32 installer (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) using the full package (except sources).
I've also set the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` and `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES` env. variables but to no avail.

I've searched, and there's quite a bit of information about it, but nothing I found helped me solve it..
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Also, what version of CMake?

Answer (score -2):

You just need to install the libssl-dev package (ubuntu)